# pillar package installation problems

Tags: r, installation

I have problems in opening excel file because of this error:

```
there is no package called pillar
```

I try to install the package, but it can't.

[image: look image 1]

I tried `devtools::install_github("r-lib/pillar")` as well but it does not work.
(I tried both with R, and with RStudio, but the problem is the same)

Comment: you could do another try with downloading the package from git and install it from source with:
`install.packages(path_to_package, repos = NULL, type="source")`

Comment: #mischva11, I'm having the same problem and found your solution, but how does one find what the "path_to_package" is?